# 150x150 crosstab in stata, showing timeseries movement between categories

Tags: time-series, stata, crosstab

I'm a bit over my head here and I hope you can help me, or at least point me in the right direction.

I got a massive dataset (5.8 mio observations per year, over 14 years), which deals with individuals' occupation over time. I need to sum up the changes in occupation in this timeperiod, so I can see from which occupation people go from and to, after periods of unemployment, like this:

[image: example1]

however, there are 150 categories, which means that I can't get stata to show the whole crosstable without linebreaks. I need to output the crosstab in .csv or some other format for further manipulation in GNU/R afterwards. So the first question is this:

1) how to extract the crosstab of this size to an csv/xls-file?

A solution would be to construct data in such a way that I can import it to SPSS, which is perfectly able to output such a huge crosstab to an excel-sheet.

Now, my data is structured like this

```
input ///
id year occup
1 1999 1
1 2000 1
1 2001 1
2 1999 1
2 2000 2
2 2001 1
3 1999 1
3 2000 2
3 2001 2
4 1999 .
4 2000 1
4 2001 2
5 1999 1
5 2000 .
5 2001 2
end
list, sepby(id)
```

As you can see, this is a simple dataframe in a long format. I need to construct the data in such a way so I can create a crosstab that shows the movement over years. E.g. one person might be occupied with "A" in 1996, then with "B" in 1997, then again in "A" in 1998. This would mean that for these two years, he would be be counted twice, as he would go from A to B and then from B to A. So the idea is that it just counts the number of shifts between categories, no matter the year.

I hope my question is asked in a clear and precise way. I do not take lightly on the fact that you spend your time on this, so if I can improve my question in any way, please say so and I will do my utmost to refine my question so as not to waste your time. Thank you in advance.

[I also asked the question on statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/939486-150x150-crosstab-in-stata-showing-timeseries-movement-between-categories)

Comment: Would you want to record movement from missing to A or B as a switch? Similarly, from A or B to missing as a switch also? And what if you have A, (.), A would you classify that as a switch from A to missing and then missing to A? Or would you classify that as no switches at all?

Comment: Example data formatted as code is more convenient than images or links.

Comment: Roberto: You're right, I updated the question accordingly.

Jignesh: Well yes I would like to record "runs" or "spells", see my comment to Robertos excellent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabout` from SSC may work for you:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data set -----

input ///
id year occup
1 1999 1
1 2000 1
1 2001 1
2 1999 1
2 2000 2
2 2001 1
3 1999 1
3 2000 2
3 2001 2
4 1999 .
4 2000 1
4 2001 2
5 1999 1
5 2000 .
5 2001 2
end

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

bysort id (year): gen fromoccup = occup[_n-1]

tabout fromoccup occup using tabtest.csv, replace cells(freq) format(0c)
```

Some assumptions are made in my calculation, but my focus is on the table. See `ssc describe tabout`.

You can also think about exporting the data set itself. Something like:

```
*----- what you want -----

bysort id (year): gen fromoccup = occup[_n-1]

collapse (count) counter=id, by(fromoccup occup)
dropmiss, obs any force

// pretty list
order fromoccup occup
sort fromoccup occup
list
```

Adjust for missings accordingly.

### Edit

Now that you have stated your goal (an adjacency matrix) it's easier to give precise help.

The following will create the adjacency matrix and export it to MS Excel. The last command `putexcel` requires Stata 13. If that's not available, you can export the Stata data set created before that, which is almost the same as the exported matrix.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data set -----

input ///
id year occup
1 1999 1
1 2000 1
1 2001 1
2 1999 1
2 2000 3
2 2001 1
3 1999 1
3 2000 3
3 2001 3
4 1999 .
4 2000 1
4 2001 3
5 1999 1
5 2000 .
5 2001 3
6 1999 4
6 2000 4
6 2001 3
end

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

bysort id (year): gen fromoccup = occup[_n-1]

collapse (count) counter=id, by(fromoccup occup)
dropmiss, obs any force

// pretty list
order fromoccup occup
sort fromoccup occup

// add combinations with zero counts
fillin fromoccup occup
replace counter = 0 if _fillin
drop _fillin

// adjacency matrix
replace counter = counter > 0
reshape wide counter, i(fromoccup) j(occup)
rename counter* occup*

list

// put into matrix, adjust, and export
mkmat _all, matrix(adjmat)

unab coln : occup*
matrix t = . , adjmat[ 1... , "fromoccup"]'

matrix colnames t = fromoccup `coln'
matrix rownames t = r0

matrix a = t \ adjmat
matrix list a

putexcel B2=matrix(a) using adjtest.xls, replace
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

For example, there are job flows from 4 to 3, but not from 3 to 4.

Comment: I'm testing your solution, it looks like it might do the trick! Will return later. One thing that definitely won't work though, is tabout. I tried it on the actual dataset, and since the final crosstab is going to have around 200-300 million observations in it, when using tabout the way you described it says "too many values". However, maybe this should be a seperate question?

Comment: This works. It also opened up the wonderfull world of using "spells" or runs to determine different states. this stata journal article is quickly proving to be an invaluable ressource, since I also need to record shifts in states. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029

Roberto, do you think I should pose a separate question about how to make a 150x150 table with 300 mio observations? Or would that be considered bad form?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. On the table issue,  I think if someone has an answer,  it should be posted here. I have my reserves on the practicality of such a table. The table should provide a summary of some information,  but a 150 x 150 table hardly qualifies,  in my view. On the other hand, let me emphasize I ignore your ultimate goal.

Comment: Allright, I will just leave it here. I agree that the table itself is quite useless as a source of overview of shifts in employment, but the idea is to feed this table to a package in GNU/R that is based on the method of social network analysis, and treat the table as an adjacency matrix, in the terminology of SNA. in this way, I'll make it into a graph that shows social mobility in occupation after periods of unemployment.

Comment: Thanks for the extra infromation. I added code to my original answer that covers the latest issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in SPSS. I've assumed you are not interested in recording the switches/migrations between missing values but are accounting for switches despite there being missings in-between valid occupational codes.

```
DATA LIST LIST /ID (F1.0) Year (F4.0) Code (A1).
BEGIN DATA.
1   1999    A
1   2000    A
1   2001    A
2   1999    A
2   2000    B
2   2001    A
3   1999    A
3   2000    B
3   2001    B
4   1999    .
4   2000    A
4   2001    B
5   1999    A
5   2000    A
5   2001    B
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DS0.

SORT CASES BY ID Year Code.

DO IF (ID=LAG(ID)).
    IF (Code=".") Code=LAG(Code).
    IF (Code<>LAG(Code) AND LAG(Code)<>".") SwitchInd=1.
END IF.
EXE.

SPLIT FILE SEPARATE BY ID.
CREATE SwitchNb=CSUM(SwitchInd).
SPLIT FILE OFF.

STRING SwitchFrom SwitchTo (A1).
DO IF (NVALID(SwitchInd)=1).
    COMPUTE SwitchFrom=LAG(Code).
    COMPUTE SwitchTo=Code.
END IF.

CTABLES /TABLE SwitchFrom[c] by SwitchTo[c] BY SwitchInd
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES = SwitchInd[1]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES = ALL EMPTY=EXCLUDE
  /TITLES CORNER="Migrations Analysis: From (Vertical) --> To (Horizontal)".
```

**Results produce (from demo data provided in testforstackexhange.csv):**

A --> B: **4**

B --> A: **1**

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make this! It looks like an elegant solution. However, I am not very profficient in spss, and since the actual data is somewhat more complicated, I cannot rely on constructing the data in spss, I need to be able to adapt the solution, which I can't do in spss. So only the final crosstab needs to be in spss. However, maybe someone else will find your solution useful.

Comment: Probably wise to have it all contained under a single platform.

Answer (score 1):

This is not my own answer, but an answer given to me from Klaudia Erhardt at [statalist.org](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/939486-150x150-crosstab-in-stata-showing-timeseries-movement-between-categories), optimised only slightly by myself. However, it was the optimal solution, so here it is:

```
clear
input ///
id year occ_code unempl
1 1999 4 0
1 2000 4 0
1 2001 . 1
1 2002 . 1
1 2003 . 1
1 2004 5 0
1 2005 5 0
1 2006 5 0
1 2007 . 1
2 1999 . 1
2 2000 . 1
2 2001 . 1
2 2002 2 0
2 2003 2 0
2 2004 . 1
2 2005 2 0
2 2006 2 0
2 2007 . 1
3 1999 1 0
3 2000 1 0
3 2001 . 1
3 2002 1 0
3 2003 . 1
3 2004 2 0
3 2005 2 0
3 2006 3 0
3 2007 . 1
4 1999 1 0
4 2000 2 0
4 2001 3 0
4 2002 4 0
4 2003 . 1
4 2004 4 0
4 2005 3 0
4 2006 . 1
4 2007 3 0
end

sort id year
tsset id year

tsspell unempl if unempl==1 //tsspel is an SSC install
rename _seq temp
drop _end _spell

replace temp = temp[_n-1]+1 if unempl==1

by id: gen occ_prev = occ_code[_n-temp[_n-1]-1] if occ_code[_n-1]==. & occ_code != .   // this is the trick!
drop temp
gen h1 = occ_prev
gen h2 = occ_code
tab2 occ_prev occ_code  // this is to control if the data set shows the same

collapse (count) occ_prev occ_code, by(h2 h1)
keep if h1 != .
drop occ_prev
reshape wide occ_code, i(h1) j(h2)
recode _all (. = 0)
```

what this does is two things:

1) creates a new variable with the employment code not from the year before, but only from the last year a person was employed. So the first year with a new employment gets a new variable with the employment code from the last time he was employed.
2) uses collapse to create a stata dataset that in effect is a crosstabulation between the employment code created in 1), and the employment code from the current year (which is always a year right after unemployment

Comment: Also, in the link provided to the statalist-question, you will find a discussion where two helpful programmers (one of them provided the solution above) discuss the pro's and con's of using two different solutions to the problem posed. Maybe this discussion will be helpfull to others as well, so if this problem is of interest to you, make the jump and check out that discussion as well.